# Riddle - "A king of pain..."

Tags: riddle, wordplay, geography

A king of pain, "Conquer!" he compelled,

A land whose name is most commonly misspelled.

People quite oriented,

A change was fated.

The rising sun was fought,

Freedom then bought.

What am I?

-Akari01 I w I

Comment: hmmm.... anyone need a hint?

Comment: I have a hunch that it's Japan because "The rising sun was fought," (and also your username) but it doesn't really fit some of the other hints like the "King of Pain" though.

Comment: It's not Japan, but something related to it... The other hint you said is w-------.

Comment: Alright, a hint would be helpful here. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> **The Philippines?**

A king of pain, "Conquer!" he compelled,

> King of **Spain,** who colonized the Philippines when Ferdinand Magellan landed on the island in 1521 and claimed it for the Spanish Empire. Hence, "conquering."

A land whose name is most commonly misspelled.

> "Philippines" is commonly misspelled, as shown when President Donald Trump famously misspelled it in a tweet.

People quite oriented,

> Reference to The Orient, hinting at Asia.

A change was fated.

The rising sun was fought,

Freedom then bought.

> I'm not sure which one of these things is being referred to here:

> Possibility #1: In 1894, the Japanese ("rising sun") offered to buy the Philippines from Spain for 40 million pounds. Spain refused, but later offered to sell them for $3,000,000, which was also turned down. In addition, during the 1896 uprising against Spanish colonial rule, some Filipino insurgents sought assistance from the Japanese government, which secretly provided them with arms.

> Possibility #2: During World War II, immediately after the attack on Pearl Harbor, Japanese forces invaded and quickly overcame resistance by the United States and Philippine Commonwealth military. The Philippines was granted back its independence by the United States in 1946.

Comment: Maybe "Oriented" refers to the Orient, which means Asia

Comment: @KingLogic Yup, I figured that was another hint to point to Japan. Although it could mean something else, I'm not 100% confident on this solution.

Comment: Correct! Its possibility #2!

Comment: A change was fated after Spain conquered the Philippines, after that, Japan fought against the Philippines while it was under the US, then after a while, it declared independency and freedom.